# Could you add a tag for "ProcessWire"?

Tags: feature-request, tags

ProcessWire is a great CMS I'm using a lot of times and for which I try to help people get their answers. Recently I saw some processwire related questions poping up on stackexchange so I thought you might could add a keyword for it which I can follow to get notifications about new questions related to it.

Greets,
Nico

Answer (score 5):

Tags are site-specific.  You need to ask on whatever site you're talking about.  That's almost certainly not *this* one; MSE is the cross-SE meta site, for questions that apply across the network.

Generally, though, you create a tag by using it on a question; tags aren't created in a void.  If you think some questions should be retagged with your new tag then, again, that's a matter for the folks at that particular site to take up.